# Calling Methods from a Variable

Tags: java

I have a variable called "line" that is from a buffered reader and will be a line from a txt log.

Sometimes I will use regex which is what Method "matches" does, regex is slower. Other times I will need to use "contains".

like below:

```
if (line.matches(problemIdExample.getFirstline())) {
      // Do stuff;
}

if (line.contains(problemIdExample.getFirstline())) {
      // Do stuff;
}
```

What I want to do is to configure "matches" or "contains" earlier in the App, so I can do something like the below

```
if (line.varibleWithMatchesOrContain(problemIdExample.getFirstline())) {
      // Do stuff;
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't work if I try the above.

Comment: Do you mean a method that just does `line.matches(problemIdExample.getFirstline()) || line.contains(problemIdExample.getFirstline())`?

Comment: No.  I want to perform only 1 operation on the line, that would do both, which is not what I want, im trying to save time, the logs are huge.

Comment: matches() is slow, contains() might be 1000 times faster. matches() can be improved if you compile the regex first. how does you problemIdExample.getFirstline() looks like? how many lines you test?

Comment: It seems like `problemIdExample.getFirstline()` just returns a String, not a regex query. Wouldn't `contains` always be true if `matches` is true?

Comment: I am buffering through 100mb of logs.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear enough. Do you mean you prefer to try contain first, and only if that doesn't work, try the matches? What do you want the `variableWithMatchesOrContain` to do, exactly? (Please [edit] the question and add the information).

Comment: I think its pretty clear?  I want to be able to switch between the 2 methods using a variable set up earlier in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Evening chaps!  Thanks for the help. I may have be able to attach a Method (of my choosing)  to a variable name I want,but it seems I would need to use Reflection.  Reflection has performance issues if you use it anyway. So I have binned the idea!

So I have gone for the answer given, I basically will have to make the choice of "contains" or "matches"(regex) as I am buffering from the text files.

My choice is 2 options only, so I have made a slight change:

```
if(variable.equals("matches")) {
    line.matches();
} else {
    line.contains();
}
```

I have picked "else" instead of "else if" because its slightly less processing, no 2nd condition to check.

The results are good. As it was, all searches had to use "matches"(regex).  Now I have the split, which means some get the the benefit of "contains" :

I scanned the same sets of logs 10 times:

Average Without switch: 2 mins 23 sec
Average With switch:    52 secs